# How do you define attribute selectors in SASS?

Tags: css, attributes, css-selectors, sass

In CSS, [you can do this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

```
input[type=submit] {
  // properties
}
```

It's a very useful for styling form buttons.

How do you do the same thing in SASS?

Comment: I only use SCSS and it works fine in that case.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can also nest it like this

```
input
  &[type="submit"]
    .... 
  &[type="search"]
    ....
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot since you'd often do this kind of thing to serve the right image from a sprite, in a toolbar or set of social links.

Comment: Adding double quote doesn't work. This shouldn't be correct answer.

Comment: &[type='submit']

Comment: Can someone put out a FULL and complete correct answer including some values being set?

Answer (score 28):

[This converter website](https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/) says:

```
input[type=submit]
  // properties
```

Comment: The link is Broken

Answer (score -1):

I use the one below in my project.

```
.bg-brand-3 {
  background-color: black;
  &[type="button"]:enabled {
    &:hover {
      background-color: orange;
    }
    &:active {
      background-color: green;
    }
  }
  &[type="submit"] {
    // css
  }
}
```

The `:enable` has the same meaning as `:not(:disabled)`