# ExtJS 4: How to theme a Field without proper variable?

Tags: extjs4, theming

I want to create a customized Ext.form.field.Field with a gray text color if the field is readOnly. If it's not readOnly, the default text color shall be used.

There seems to be no variable in the _form.scss -file that can be used to do that.

Can I create a new variable like **$form-field-readonly-color** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final solution is:

```
.x-form-field.x-form-text[readonly]  {
    color: gray !important;
}
```

Textfields have the two classes x-form-field and x-form-text. Attribute "readonly" is set by ExtJS and can be selected with brackets, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789167/how-do-you-define-attribute-selectors-in-sass).

This code can be pasted directly in the scss-file so it doesn't pollute any Ext-files.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the defaults by using your own CSS:

```
.x-item-disabled {
    color: #888888 !important;
    -moz-opacity: 100;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
    zoom: 1;
}
.x-form-item-label .x-item-disabled {
    color: #888888 !important;
    -moz-opacity: 100;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
    zoom: 1;
}
```

can't vouch for the overide to be of quality but classes are correct.

Comment: +1 because your post pushed me in the right direction. You forget to mention the readOnly-part so I postet a complete answer.